# Decrease the size of a graph in ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, size

I have two questions for this graph I did:

[image]

The first, is how do I decrease the graph size?, I have tried with `coord_fixed`:

```
ggplot(x, aes(fill=is_pass, y=percent_diff, x=difficulty_level)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 0.05)
```

But it just change the dimension's ratio of the graph, not the size. I'm looking for a simple answer, something like:

```
ggplot(x, aes(fill=is_pass, y=percent_diff, x=difficulty_level)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    size(width=5, length=4) # or something like this
```

The second question, is that `is_pass` is defined as a factor with just two classes 0 and 1. However, ggplots takes `is_pass` as numeric and doesn't plot it as classes 0 and 1 as you can see in the graph. Why?

Comment: `is_pass` is `numeric`, therefore ggplot sees it as a continuous variable (even if there are only two distinct values). If you want ggplot to recognize it as a factor or discrete that it is, then perhaps use `fill=factor(is_pass)` and your legend will reflect the discrete nature of it.

Comment: When you say the "size" of the plot, where exactly are you looking at the plot? Are you saving it to an image file or something? On the screen. the plot will resize to whatever window you are looking at it with. `ggplot` objects don't really have a "size."

Answer (score 4):

As for the size, you could try maybe setting margins in your theme, something like:

```
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

margins work as t, r, b, l.

Comment: I have been playing with it, and it seems to works sometimes, but I don't understand very well how it works the coordinates c(1,1,1,1).. and what do you mean with t,r,b,l ?

Comment: The coordinates are Top, Right, Bottom, Left. You can also change to other unit different than "cm" if you want

Comment: also don't forget to accept one of the answers here

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time since this question has been asked. I had a similar issue. I wanted to have the graph itself smaller, but not any of the text in the graph! I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for. But for me, adjusting the fig.height in the chunk helped:

{r fig.height = 10, fig.width = 5}

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the size of bar by adding `width` in `geom_bar()`
like this: `geom_bar(..., width=0.1)`

And I don't get what second question is exactly referring to. As `is_pass` has factor level, it seems to quite make sense that factor value is featured by two different colors.

Comment: the width=0.1 in geom_bar allows just to change the width of the each bar, not the size of the graph. And the graph plot two different colors, but if you see the legend of is_pass it shows a range of colors, not two colors (that's my question essentially).

Answer (score 0):

It may meet your need to set the size of the graphics window before you call ggplot.

```
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
```

You may need to experiment to get the size that you want.

Here is a complete example.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

dev.new(width=5, height=4)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: Two barplots]

You can see that the second plot is much smaller.

Comment: It doesn't work. Simply doesn't plot anything when I put that line of code before I call ggplot. Do you know why it could be?

Comment: Odd. It works fine for me.  I will include an example